# The system can not find the path specified in ftp 550 error

Tags: ftp

try
            {
                _ftpClient = ConnectToServer(_file, _FtpType, _DbOperations, _ftpClient);

```
            if (_ftpClient == null)
                return "";


            _ftpClient.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
            _ftpClient.UsePassive = true;
            _ftpClient.KeepAlive = false;
            _ftpClient.UseBinary = true;
            _ftpClient.RenameTo = "../" + _FtpType.P_SourceFolderTemp + "/" + _file;
            _ftpClient.GetResponse();
            return "1";
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            string hata = ((FtpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusDescription;
            //_DbOperations.Logla(_BBSFtpType, "j");
            _DbOperations.DbExceptions(_BBSFtpType);
            return "0";
        }
```

the program falls catch and status description is 550-The system cannot find the path specified.Win32 error:   The system cannot find the path specified. Error details: File system returned an error.550 End. What can I do to correct it?

Comment: use the correct path? It might be that the FTP server will not accept relative path with "../".

Comment: For example how can the correct path be?

Comment: "ftp://" + _FtpType.P_FtpHost + ":" + _FtpType.P_Port + "/" + _FtpType.P_SourceFolderTemp + "/" + _file; is this correct path?

Comment: How should I know what the correct path is on your server? "The system cannot find the path specified." means just what it says, that is you specified a path which is not there. This might be a non-existing file or directory. It might also be that the server is case-sensitive and you used the wrong case etc.

Comment: Sorry, this is my fault because I have written the folder name false.